# What's wrong with this bash script (Linux Debian 10)

Tags: bash

Seems that I can't make this script to work:

```
#!/bin/bash

command="/usr/bin/paste -d'|' <(echo -n \$(id)) <(echo -n \$(id)) 2>&1"

output=`$command`

echo "$output"
```

The command works fine if executed from shell:

```
/usr/bin/paste -d'|' <(echo -n $(id)) <(echo -n $(id)) 2>&1
```

Any idea why it doesn't work from the bash script?

Comment: `<(echo -n $(id))`? Why? It looks like useless use of echo. Just `<(id)`. The newline missing or not makes no difference at least for my `paste`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a function, not a string. The results of simple parameter expansion are not fully reparsed; they only undergo word splitting and pathname expansion.

```
# command is the name of a built-in command; best not to shadow it
# without a really good reason.
yourCommand () {
    /usr/bin/paste -d'|' <(echo -n $(id)) <(echo -n $(id)) 2>&1
}

output=$(yourCommand)

echo "$output"
```

Comment: Can you take a look at this new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62741524/2972081