# Bash script with long command as a concatenated string

Tags: bash

Here is a sample bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

array[0]="google.com"
array[1]="yahoo.com"
array[2]="bing.com"

pasteCommand="/usr/bin/paste -d'|'"

for val in "${array[@]}"; do 
    pasteCommand="${pasteCommand} <(echo \$(/usr/bin/dig -t A +short $val)) "
done

output=`$pasteCommand`

echo "$output"
```

Somehow it shows an error:

```
/usr/bin/paste: invalid option -- 't'
Try '/usr/bin/paste --help' for more information.
```

How can I fix it so that it works fine?

//EDIT:

Expected output is to get result from the 3 dig executions in a string delimited with | character. Mainly I am using paste that way because it allows to run the 3 dig commands in parallel and I can separate output using a delimiter so then I can easily parse it and still know the dig output to which domain (e.g google.com for first result) is assigned.

Comment: What is the expected output ? Seems really fragile and buggy

Comment: Process substitution isn't well-suited for dynamically generated commands like this.

Comment: The variable `pasteCommand` is overwritten on each iteration...

Comment: I think you want something like `iplist="${iplist} $(echo $(/usr/bin/dig -t A +short $val)) "`, but I don't know how the output should look like.

Comment: @GillesQuenot `paste -d "|" <(dig ...) <(dig ...) <(dig ...)`, with one process substitution per array element.

Comment: @GillesQuenot I added the requested details

Comment: Read [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: you should take a look at the bash builtin `eval` command: eval: eval [arg ...]
    Read ARGs as input to the shell and execute the resulting command(s).

Comment: @user2972081 Please do not ask XY questions... Please specify what you want to do. And as I commented in your previous question `<(echo $(..))` is a useless use of echo just `<(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to ask a question when you specify input and desired output in your question, then specify your try and why doesn't it work.

> What i want is https://i.postimg.cc/13dsXvg7/required.png

```
$ array=("google.com" "yahoo.com" "bing.com")
$ printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | xargs -n1 sh -c '/usr/bin/dig -t A +short "$1" | paste -sd" "' _ | paste -sd '|'
172.217.16.14|72.30.35.9 98.138.219.231 98.137.246.7 98.137.246.8 72.30.35.10 98.138.219.232|204.79.197.200 13.107.21.200
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly! I will add more details in the question the next time.

Answer (score 3):

First, you should read [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) to understand why your approach failed. In short, do not put complex commands inside variables.

A simple bash script to give intended output could be something like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

sites=(google.com yahoo.com bing.com)
iplist=
for site in "${sites[@]}"; do
# Capture command's output into ips variable
    ips=$(/usr/bin/dig -t A +short "$site")
# Prepend a '|' character, replace each newline character in ips variable
# with a space character and append the resulting string to the iplist variable
    iplist+=\|${ips//$'\n'/' '}
done
iplist=${iplist:1} # Remove the leading '|' character
echo "$iplist"
```

outputs

```
172.217.18.14|98.137.246.7 72.30.35.9 98.138.219.231 98.137.246.8 72.30.35.10 98.138.219.232|13.107.21.200 204.79.197.200
```

Answer (score 1):

I might try a recursive function like the following instead.

```
array=(google.com yahoo.com bing.com)

paster () {
    
    dn=$1
    shift

    if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
        dig -t A +short "$dn"
    else
        paster "$@" | paste -d "|" <(dig -t A +short "$dn") -
    fi
}

output=$(paster "${array[@]}")

echo "$output"
```

Comment: You examples gives this output: https://i.postimg.cc/DyB2kv7T/output.png What I require is this: https://i.postimg.cc/13dsXvg7/required.png

Comment: I suggest you add your expected output (as *text*) to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Now finally clear with expected output:

```sh
domains_arr=("google.com" "yahoo.com" "bing.com")
out_arr=()
for domain in "${domains_arr[@]}"
do
  mapfile -t ips < <(dig -tA +short "$domain")
  IFS=' '
  # Join the ips array into a string with space as delimiter
  # and add it to the out_arr
  out_arr+=("${ips[*]}")
done
IFS='|'
# Join the out_arr array into a string with | as delimiter
echo "${out_arr[*]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array is big (and not just 3 sites) you may benefit from parallelization:

```
array=("google.com" "yahoo.com" "bing.com")
parallel -k 'echo $(/usr/bin/dig -t A +short {})' ::: "${array[@]}" |
  paste -sd '|'
```